# Changing the default placeholder in a Django model form for a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have my code set up as follows:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('category',)
        widgets = {
            #'category' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Select the category'}),
        }
```

Basically, right now, without the widgets part, I get `--------` as the placeholder for this field. However, I want to get 'Select the category', how can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set custom placeholder using [empty_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) field:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label='Select the category')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```