# django avoid ------ in forms created by ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a ForeignKey field and I am using django generics CBV for create and update the model. So when I extend from CreateView the resulting input is a select, but with its first option set as

```
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
```

I dont want this behavior, I need something like

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
```

Comment: Maybe this answers helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710970/changing-the-default-placeholder-in-a-django-model-form-for-a-foreignkey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the default placeholder in a Django model form for a ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710970/changing-the-default-placeholder-in-a-django-model-form-for-a-foreignkey)

Comment: I want to avoid do a Form class.